# Update column "total price" in orders table using other columns (pizza_price*pizza_amount) in different tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

This is relational diagram of database I created:

[image]

I need to **insert** total price in `Orders.Total_Price` column by multiplying the `Pizza.Pizza_Price` value with `Order.Pizza_Amount`.

I'm a beginner so I don't have idea how actually to do it. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE order o ,pizza p
SET o.total_price = p.pizza_price * o.pizza_amount
where o.pizza_id = p.pizza_Id;
```

This query will update information from two different tables, and it will take less time if there are too many records.

Answer (score 1):

You need an update with a JOIN statement for this.

```
UPDATE order
SET o.Total_Price = p.Pizza_Price * o.Pizza_Amount
FROM
  order AS o
INNER JOIN 
  Pizza AS p ON p.Pizza_Id = O.Pizza_id
```